# How to convert file in .glade extension to .xml on windows 7

Tags: windows, gtk, glade

i have set up GTK and glade in windows 7 but cant find program which convert glade output to xml..kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension from `.glade` to `.xml`. In that regard windows did not get mature in decades.